# Rotate a shape around a point smoothly in high density devices in Java, not JavaScript

Tags: android, canvas, game-physics

I'm trying to rotate a shape around a point with `sin` and `cos` functions, the code is working well in phones with 720*1280dpi density=320dpi, but in high-density devices that has 1080*1920 (density=480dpi).

And this is how I try to rotate the shape, I need the X and Y, so I can't change the algorithm.

I try to increment angle in a time loop:

```
repeatTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        angle += 0.01;
    }
}, 0, speed);
```

And then in an `onDraw` function, I try to find the next X and Y by:

```
x1 = ((float)(distance) * Math.cos(angle));
y1 = ((float)(distance) * Math.sin(angle));
```

Then I use this point to draw a shape:

```
canvas.drawCircle(x1, y1, radius, paint);
```

I changed the timer speed value many times, also changed FRAME_RATE to 100,50 and some other values, it didn't solve the issue, changed the increment step to any value, but again the rotate animation is not smooth in high-density devices.

There were some questions that discuss the issue and I didn't get how to solve the problem.

Comment: How is it not working?  Telling us its broken without telling us how its broken is unlikely to get you a good answer.

Comment: If its performance-  you actually need to profile and see where you're spending time.  Its unlikely to be this code directly.

Comment: no, it's not a performance issue, because of buttons and touches response  well

Comment: Just because the buttons respond well doesn't mean the system is able to cope with rendering at high framerates - the related timescales are very different (~100ms vs ~10ms).

Comment: Cpu usage show everything is normal, and the app uses about 3 percents